# In QGIS Layout "Export as image" predefined settings do not match Page Properties

Tags: qgis, print-composer, dpi

When setting the Page properties in the Print Layout I expected that these properties are predefined when exporting this Layout as image. But either this seems not to be the case or I am missing something.

In my example I set the Page Properties to page height and page width each 100 mm. In the Layout variables this is shown as layout_pageheight = 100 and layout_pagewidth = 100. Also I set the dpi (dots per inch) to 300.

My assumption was that these seetings are used as predefined values to calculate the page size when exporting the map as an image. This would be a page height and width of 7620 (`10 cm * 2.54 cm/inch * 300 dpi`). Instead the preset value is 1181 px.

Is this an error, not implemented or is my calculation/assumption not valid?

[image: image showing the mismatch between layout settings and export options]

Comment: Your calculation is wrong : 100mm is 3,937inch  (=100/25.4) and 3,937x300=1181 so 100mm at 300ppi correspond indeed to 1181px

Comment: To get inches you need to multiply the `cm` by `in/cm`, not `cm/in`

Comment: haha, damn, of course its the other way around and I just messed up my calculation. Should not do that if tired.